# Gradle Source Set dependency does not work with Jigsaw Modules

Tags: java, gradle, module, java-platform-module-system

Consider the following gradle project:

---

src/foo/module-info.java

```
module foo {}
```

---

src/bar/module-info.java

```
module bar {
    requires foo;
}
```

---

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    foo {
        java { srcDir 'src/foo' }
    }
    bar {
        java { srcDir 'src/bar' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    barCompile sourceSets.foo.output
}

compileBarJava.dependsOn 'compileFooJava'
```

---

When running `gradle compileBarJava`, the java compiler gives the following error:

```
src/bar/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: foo
requires foo;
         ^
```

Why is that? After all, the way the `bar` source set is set up is that it should fully depend on `foo`. If there were a class in the `bar` source set that depended on a class in `foo`, the compiler would not complain.

Comment: what does your task `compileFooJava` do? Does it create a module `foo`?

Comment: It's the default compilation task that is created by the Java plugin. So it compiles the `src/foo` directory.

Comment: not very good at gradle, yet shouldn't it follow https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module  to be used further as a module?